# Dividing google map in subregions

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps Javascript V3 with Android.

I'd like to highlight different districts of a city in google map with different colors. So how would I be able to get the boundaries of a certain region from google map?

I want to do a sort of segmentation like zillow does, maybe more refined at closer levels:

http://www.zillow.com/homes/san-diego_rb/0-_price/0-_mp/#/homes/for_sale/San-Diego-CA/54296_rid/zest_sort/32.958357,-116.924877,32.795448,-117.456684_rect/11_zm/0_mmm/1_fr/

So is there a trivial way from the API to retrieve some boundaris positions?

Answer (score 1):

These layers  will be a custom layers on top of the Map rendered using JS APIs. You will have to store the lat longs of the regions and create a polygon using Custom Overlays. Please refer to the link below

```
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polygons
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking more regarding the segmentation of the map. I guess there are many different ways but since I think this is not a new problem and someone else must have solved I was hoping in some advices regarding this.